# What can two tables make this behavior?

Tags: sql, oracle

Have in a big oracle database 2 tables. Left the objects, I want the name of.
Right I have a table where are attributes. I wanted to find the rows with the names which don't have any attribute.
For that I used a left outer join query - and got only the names of the left table, where attributes on the right.
Usually I see both. But not with this 2 tables.
Tried with NVL, COALESCE, nothing gives me the NULL-rows back.
Whatever could be the reason make this behavior.

(Sorry for not give code or example, I could not simulate the behavior. Other outerjoins do what they used to do.)

Comment: Please provide sample data and the results you are seeing and the results you want.

Answer (score 0):

I would think of `not exists`.  You have very limited information in the question.  But the idea is:

```
select n.*
from names n
where not exists (select 1 from attributes a where a.name = n.name);
```

Comment: Sorry for not having more Information wasn't able to reproduce this with other tables.

Answer (score 0):

The way I understood the question, MINUS set operator might help:

```
select names from left
minus
select names from right;
```

Comment: Sorry for not adding more information, wasn't able to reproduce this behavior. But I connected both tables by an ident, which is the foreign key in the right table and the primary in the left. So in other tables i use the leftouterjoin to see all names left and attrbutes if there are not given with null. This 2 tables only show names of the left when there are attributes with this key on the right (could be more than 1, 3 kinds of datatypes: number, date and varchar). Thanks for thinking and answers, i try it monday. Maybe i will get the attributes